# identity template and attribute node cannot be created

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, identity

I am using the identity template in XSLT and normally it works quite well. For the current batch of files I am getting 
'An attribute node (class) cannot be created after a child of the containing element'.

If I understand this error message correctly, it tells me that I am trying to add an attribute on one element, but that the "cursor" has moved to the child element... 
How do I prevent this?

This is the template:

```
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:copy>
```

After I posted this, I found one suggestion in another similar question. Which was something in the line of: Create a match on @*
So I added this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <!-- don't do a thing -->
</xsl:template>
```

And the error message is gone and everything works.

Comment: Please show us a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem. So far you have not even shown a complete template.

Comment: The problem typically arises if you have a template rule that processes elements and creates attributes. Any template rule that creates attributes without creating the containing element is potentially suspect. (By which I don't mean it's wrong, just that it's a potential source of this error.) But we can't debug your code without seeing it.

Comment: The problem with your "solution" is that it removes **all** attributes in the source XML from appearing at the output. If that's the desired result, then it can be achieved much more simply by not applying **any** templates to attributes to begin with - including the identity transform template. If it's not, then you have successfully suppressed the error message at the expense of damaging the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identity Template confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860844/identity-template-confusion)